# Static variable variables in php 5.2

Tags: php

I'm trying to define the following function:

```
function set($key, $value, $default = null)
    {
    if ($value)
        static $$key = $value;
    else
        static $$key = $default;
    }
```

But when I call it, I get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting T_VARIABLE". I guess there is a problem with defining static variable variables, but I can't find a workaround. Can you? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use such an outdated php version?

Comment: Oops!! I meant to write PHP 5.2! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really wanted to do something like that, I'd use a static array instead:

```
function set($key, $value, $default = null)
{
    static $values = array();
    $values[$key] = is_null($value) ? $default : $value;
}
```

If you want to also be able to access this data, a better idea is to encapsulate it in a class.

```
class Registry
{
    private static $values = array();

    public static function set($key, $value, $default = null)
    {
        self::$values[$key] = is_null($value) ? $default : $value;
    }

    public static function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, self::$values) ? self::$values[$key] : $default;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the class statically:

```
Registry::set('key', 'value', 'default');
$value = Registry::get('key', 'default');
```

An even better way of doing this is to not use the `static` keyword at all, and instead make a normal class with normal properties, then make a single instance of it and use that instance.

```
class Registry
{
    private $values = array();

    public function set($key, $value, $default = null)
    {
        $this->values[$key] = is_null($value) ? $default : $value;
    }

    public function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->values) ? $this->values[$key] : $default;
    }
}
```

You can then make an instance of the class and pass it along:

```
$registry = new Registry();
do_something_that_requires_the_registry($registry);
```

Comment: @LFS, how do you plan to access these variables after you set them inside a static variable in the `set()` function?

Comment: Damn.. I am beginning to think that I misunderstood completely the workings of the static keyword.. Now I want to remove my question, as it might not make any sense..

Comment: I thought that by using the static keyword I could access the variable from outside the function.. but I cannot, right?

Comment: @LFS, the question does make sense. I added an example of how what you're trying to achieve might work.

Comment: @LFS, no, static variables have the same scope as any other variable. What you're thinking about are [global variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). It would be wise however to avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing this in a class, you can use the `__get` and `__set` magic functions.

I use it like this in my projects:

```
class foo
{

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->vals[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->vals[$key];
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar = "test";
echo $foo->bar;
```